# Generate rows with index between two numbers

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a single table varchar, int, int like this:

```
OS          MinSP      MaxSP
--          -----      -----
2000        4          4
XP          2          3
Vista       0          2
7           0          1
```

What I want is a query which will generate a list of values like this:

- 2000 SP4
- XP SP2
- XP SP3
- Vista
- Vista SP1
- Vista SP2
- 7
- 7 SP1

*Edit*

Although MinSP and MaxSP a never more than one apart in my original example, it's possible that they will both be the same or separated by more than one.  I've changed the example to illustrate.

Comment: What if the minversion is not 1 step lower than the maxversion?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific about that, will edit question.

Comment: Do you want a pure query ('cause, ew), or would calling a stored procedure like Tobiasopdenbrow suggested be acceptable?

Comment: The stored procedure will probably work, but for now I'm using your solution and have just made sure none of my values differ by more than one so I can get on with the rest of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a [Tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) to do the following, but it beats a cursor and will grow dynamically with the next OS that is released.  Your tally table will have to be zero based too.

*EDIT: Fixed a typo and added a second version*

Version 1 (You have not got a Tally Table):
This generates a numbers table on the fly using sys.all_columns. There are many ways of doing this, but you get the idea.

```
;WITH    Tally(N)
          AS (SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 --minus one to make this zero based
              FROM      sys.all_columns C)
    SELECT  OS + CASE WHEN N > 0 THEN ' SP' + CAST(B.N AS char(1))
                      ELSE ''
                 END
    FROM    dbo.Test A
    INNER JOIN Tally B ON B.N >= A.MinSp
                          AND B.N <= A.MaxSp
```

Version two (You have a Tally Table that is zero based):

```
SELECT  OS + CASE WHEN N > 0 THEN ' SP' + CAST(B.N AS char(1))
                  ELSE ''
             END
FROM    dbo.Test A
INNER JOIN dbo.Tally B ON B.N >= A.MinSp
                          AND B.N <= A.MaxSp
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:

```
Select OS + ' SP' + Convert(varchar(50),MinSp) as col1 from TABLE
UNION 
Select OS + ' SP' + Convert(varchar(50),MaxSp) as col1 from TABLE
```

Add ORDER BY as desired.

But see my comment to your question as well.

Comment: Thanks, as you surmise my example didn't fully illustrate all the possibilities, I've edited the question as a result.

Comment: @robertc In that case, and assuming SP's only increment in whole integer steps, I'd create a stored procedure that combines the following steps:

1. Iterate over your input table (cursor), and for each row:
2. Fire a For loop over the MaxSP-MinSP range (0,1,2 in your 'Vista' row) and for each step in the loop create the correct string in a (temp) table (test for '0' to create the correct string)
3. Output the temp table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MinSP = '0' THEN OS ELSE OS + ' SP' + cast(MinSP as 
    nvarchar(10)) END AS Results, MaxSP
FROM OS

UNION

SELECT CASE WHEN MaxSP = '0' THEN OS ELSE OS + ' SP' + cast(MaxSP as 
    nvarchar(10)) END AS Results, MaxSP
FROM OS
ORDER BY MaxSP DESC
```

EDIT:

And with your new criteria, I've assumed you'll have a second table called SPNums, which is filled with as many numbers as you think you'll need, starting with 0.

```
SPNum
-----
   0
   1 
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
```

And then the query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SPNum = '0' THEN OS ELSE OS + ' SP' + cast(SPNum as 
    nvarchar(10)) END AS Results
FROM OS
LEFT OUTER JOIN SPNums ON SPNum >= MinSP AND SPNum <= MaxSP
ORDER BY OS
```

Comment: Ah yes, version 0 drops the 'SP' tag. Good point. Still, the OP should consider the scenario where maxsp<>minsp + 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edited the question following Tobiasopdenbrouw's comment